# How to preview PDF using PDF Viewer on an Grails Application

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

I'm a novice Grails Programmer.I have 2 use case :

1. render image file show on GSP Page.
2. render PDF file and show on PDF Viewer integrate with GSP Page.

Can anyone provide examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Please provide some more details for your actions but roughly I suspect you might want the following:

1. `<img src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: '1.jpg')}" alt="Image"/>`
2. I don't know of any PDF viewers that could be integrated with an HTML page let alone a one that would be specific to grails. Your best bet is to redirect people to the PDF file and let their own browser handle the file.